# Client has to use Jersey asynchron lib if server using Jersey Asynchron library?

Tags: asynchronous, jersey

I'm reading Jersey asynchorn library doc, and wondering if I have to use jersey asynchron library in client if server uses it?

If not, how can chunkoutput/chunkinput be handled?

How about other asynchornous libraries?

Thank you in advance!